# Hexagon shapes of list have defects css

Tags: css, list, division

So, I am wondering why this one div doesn't have same smooth edges just like the others when they have the same codes, I'm confused as to what might be the cause of this.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: We can't possibly know without seeing your code. Please update your question so that it shows your existing code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEgKva

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="hexTop"></div>
  <div class="hexBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
    .hexagon {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; 
  height: 173.21px;
  margin: 86.60px 0;
  background-image: url(http://csshexagon.com/img/meow.jpg);
  background-size: auto 346.4102px;
  background-position: center;
}

.hexTop,
.hexBottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 212.13px;
  height: 212.13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scaleY(0.5774) rotate(-45deg);
  background: inherit;
  left: 43.93px;
}

/*counter transform the bg image on the caps*/
.hexTop:after,
.hexBottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 300.0000px;
  height: 173.20508075688775px;
  -webkit-transform:  rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  -ms-transform:      rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  transform:          rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.7321) translateY(-86.6025px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: inherit;
}

.hexTop {
  top: -106.0660px;
}

.hexTop:after {
  background-position: center top;
}

.hexBottom {
  bottom: -106.0660px;
}

.hexBottom:after {
  background-position: center bottom;
}

.hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.0000px;
  left: 0;
  width: 300.0000px;
  height: 173.2051px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: inherit;
}
```